# Which Gentoo profile?

Tags: linux, gentoo, vmware

I'm installing Gentoo as a guest on a VMware virtual machine on an iMac host.  I'm asked to select a profile and the list has 22 options.

```
[1]  default/linux/amd64/10.0
[2]  default/linux/amd64/10.0/selinux
[3]  default/linux/amd64/10.0/desktop
[4]  default/linux/amd64/10.0/desktop/gnome
...
[7]  default/linux/amd64/10.0/no-multilib *
...
[10] default/linux/amd64/13.0
...
```

Currently the 10.0/no-multilib profile is selected.

I'm intending to use the virtual machine for experimenting, web browsing, running things that the Mac doesn't offer or that I don't want to install permanently.

I will probably run neither Gnome nor KDE but a lightweight WM. I am inclined to select the 'desktop' profile, but which should I use, 10 or 13 (and what happened to 11 and 12)?  What do the 10/13 mean? They don't seem to correspond to a Gentoo 'version'.

I've got the no-multilib profile currently because I downloaded the nm stage3.  Perhaps I should stick with the no-multilib profile and adjust the USE flags?

Comment: multilib is still required by many applications

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would select the latest version vanilla desktop profile. That shows 12 on my system (using `eselect profile list`).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend against 'no-multilib' as many programs require that. If you are following along with the Gentoo handbook you should see that the ['Desktop' profile](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-amd64.xml?part=1&chap=6#doc_chap2) is recommended for most users. You should therefore use the latest 'Desktop' profile which is:

default/linux/amd64/13.0/Desktop

I believe the numbers are legacy and refer to [yearly live media](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentoo_Linux#Release-media_version_history) (this is complete speculation), though Gentoo's release model is rolling.

In any case I had no problems installing a functioning system with */13.0/Desktop

Comment: Thanks. I already went ahead with the 10.0/Desktop, which completed successfully. I noticed somewhere that the 10.0 ones are mostly marked 'stable' and the 13.0 ones are marked 'dev'. So I went with the stable ones. Since then I've done a full update command and it is now busy merging 194 packages - so perhaps I end up with the 13.0 situation - or perhaps not.

Answer (score 2):

See this blog post for more information:

http://dilfridge.blogspot.de/2013/02/gentoo-100-to-130-profiles-upgrade.html

Comment: Please summarize a bit why this link is relevant.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I wanted. Sadly, I had so many problems installing (last straw I think was firefox failing to merge) that I gave up and install debian instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the latest version 13 of the desktop profile. This will allow you to install a windows manager without having to install gnome or kde.